# Внешняя VGA to Notebook

Tags: сервер, vga, видеокарта

Здравствуйте, есть локальный сервер на ноутбуке. Возможно ли подключить внешнюю отдельную VGA к ноутбуку, есть ли специальный переходник, либо что-нибудь еще подключаемое к порту ноутбука и позволяющее работать внешней подключенной к нему VGA?

Answer (score 0):

Хех, у вас очень интересный вопрос. Есть возможность подключать внешнюю видеокарту через порт MiniPCI-e, тот, в который подключается модуль Wifi. Для этого вам нужно соответствующее оборудование. http://www.notebookcheck-ru.com/Vneshnjaja-igrovaja-videokarta-dlja-noutbuka-Rasskazhem-kak.112308.0.html можете здесь глянуть.